# How to return kotlin selectors in an interface override function so they can be used by the compareValuesBy function?

Tags: kotlin

I'm somewhat new to Kotlin, but trying some advanced stuff (I think).

I have the following interface and class that uses the interface. My goal is to allow any type of class to extend the `Syncable` interface and use those within a `SyncableWrapper` so that I can compare an object to the previous version of itself. There will be various types of `Syncable` classes that implement it, each with a different set of fields that will be included in the comparison.

So I'd like to have each class that extends `Syncable` override `getSelectorsToCompareValuesBy` and return the selectors that are needed to compare the class object to another version of itself. Although these happen to be kotlin data classes, I can't just use `==` because some properties are not going to be included in the comparison, and I'd like to be able to choose per class which are included and which aren't.

I can't just override `.equals()` in the `data class` because there are times when I need to compare all of the fields, and other times I need to compare based on the selectors I want to return in `getSelectorsToCompareValuesBy()`.

```
interface Syncable {
    fun <T> getSelectorsToCompareValuesBy(): (T) -> Comparable<T>
}

class SyncableWrapper<T: Syncable>(
        val previous: T,
        val changed: T
) {
    fun comparePrevToChanged(): Int = compareValuesBy(previous, changed,
                previous.getSelectorsToCompareValuesBy()
        )
}
```

For more context, the `SyncableWrapper` objects will be passed through a Spring Boot API as a @ResponseBody, but this Kotlin question doesn't really relate to that. I'll run `comparePrevToChanged()` and do other things with each of the objects.

I tried something like this (which of course doesn't compile)...

```
data class Something (
        val fieldToCompareWith1: String,
        val fieldToCompareWith2: String,
        val fieldToCompareWith3: String,
        val fieldToIgnore: String,
): Syncable {
        override fun <Something> getSelectorsToCompareValuesBy(): (Something) -> Comparator<Something> {
                return {
                {it.fieldToCompareWith1}, {it.fieldToCompareWith2}, {it.fieldToCompareWith3}
                }
        }
}
```

What can I do? I think my `comparePrevToChanged()` fun is fine and my `getSelectorsToCompareValuesBy` signature is fine or pretty close. Maybe I'm just not overriding correctly in order to return the selector, or maybe my return type is wrong as well. Maybe I should be overriding `Comparable.compareTo` instead and forget the whole thing.

But the real nature of this question is: Can you pass function selectors as an argument, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

```
fun main() {
    val wrapper = SyncableWrapper(
        Something("1", "2", "3", "4"),
        Something("1", "2", "3", "5")
    )
    println(wrapper.comparePrevToChanged()) // 0
}

interface Syncable<T> {
    val comparator: Comparator<T>
}

class SyncableWrapper<T : Syncable<T>>(
    val previous: T,
    val changed: T
) {
    fun comparePrevToChanged(): Int = previous.comparator.compare(previous, changed)
}

data class Something(
    val fieldToCompareWith1: String,
    val fieldToCompareWith2: String,
    val fieldToCompareWith3: String,
    val fieldToIgnore: String
) : Syncable<Something> {
    override val comparator: Comparator<Something>
        get() = compareBy({ it.fieldToCompareWith1 }, { it.fieldToCompareWith2 }, { it.fieldToCompareWith3 })
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I did end up doing something like this, but it doesn't really answer my question whether you can actually return the selectors themselves and not a Comparator. It is more of a language question of what is possible than looking for a different solution.

Comment: @DanielGibby you can return array of selectors `return arrayOf<(Something) -> Comparator<Something>>({ it.fieldToCompareWith1 }, { it.fieldToCompareWith2 }, { it.fieldToCompareWith3 })` and use Spread Operator in `compareValuesBy(previous, changed, *getSelectorsToCompareValuesBy())` or you can return selector, that returns comparable object with the values required for comparison(eg `Triple`), `return { Triple(it.fieldToCompareWith1, it.fieldToCompareWith2, it.fieldToCompareWith3) }`

Comment: OK, thank you @IR42! The spread operator is something I don't remember hearing about. I'll have to look into that. I can't use ```Pair``` or ```Triple``` because there will be a dynamic number of selectors depending on the class that extends ```Syncable```.